# uploading files using background transfer request method in windows phone 8

Tags: php, windows-phone-8, file-upload, background-transfer

I am trying to upload a file to a local http server`(http://192.168.1.123/upload.php)` using background transfer request method in windows phone 8. Server will save the file after getting file name from `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`. `[Ex: if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['name']`))  {//save the file}].

I am also uploading the file from `"/shared/transfers/"` directory of isolated storage. Debugging shows that the statuscode= 200. 'BytesSent' property of background transfer request shows the actual size of the file. But the server can't save the file. What may be the possible cause for the problem? How can i send file name properly in background transfer request?

Comment: you sure this is your client side problem?

Comment: yes. Files are being uploaded from android platform. but windows background transfer seems not working. server cant get any name for $_FILES['userfile']['name']. can you suggest how i can send the name of the file properly??